# Why i always have an empty value in drop down

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am showing a simple drop down from list of string. I always have an empty dropdown option available even if i do't want to have it. As shown in image

[image]

```
//predefined values for brandingSpaceType 
private brandingSpaceTypeValues: string[] = ["Mobile Shop", "Supermarket", 
"Shop In Shop", "Shop On Wheel", "Kiosk", "Others"]
private selectedBrandingSpaceType: string = this.brandingSpaceTypeValues[2];
```

And here is html

```
<div class="field">
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectUndefinedOptionValue" 
name="brandingSpaceType" [disabled]="brandingSpaceTypeStatus.readonly">
<option [selected]="selectedBrandingSpaceType == x" *ngFor="let x of 
brandingSpaceTypeValues" [value]="x">{{x}}<option>
</select>{{selectUndefinedOptionValue}}
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. How much it wasted my time can't tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your html. You have to close your option tag properly like`</option>`

```
<option [selected]="selectedBrandingSpaceType == x" *ngFor="let x of 
brandingSpaceTypeValues" [value]="x">{{x}}</option>
```

Try this it will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your select

```
<option disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
```

- `disabled` makes option unclickable.
- `style='display: none'` to not displayed in older browsers.

---

```
<div class="field">

<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectUndefinedOptionValue" 
name="brandingSpaceType" [disabled]="brandingSpaceTypeStatus.readonly">

<option disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>

<option [selected]="selectedBrandingSpaceType == x" *ngFor="let x of 
brandingSpaceTypeValues" [value]="x">{{x}}<option>

</select>{{selectUndefinedOptionValue}}
</div>
```

Comment: try to set by default the first no empty value